# Leer archivo de propiedades de desarrollo o produccion en spring boot

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, archivo-de-propiedades

tengo la siguiente cuestión, como puedo leer un archivo de `.properties` desde spring boot dependiendo el ambiente en que me encuentro?
Mi estructura del proyecto es la siguiente:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

He leído [esto](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34845990/spring-use-one-application-properties-for-production-and-another-for-debug) pero no consigo hacer que funcione.

Gracias.

Answer (score 1):

Ese link si funciona la idea es que tu lo corras una vez generado tu jar. Ejemplo una vez construido tu jar entonces podrías ejecutar de esta manera:

```
java - jar yourproject.jar --spring.profiles.active=dev
```

O

```
java - jar yourproject.jar --spring.profiles.active=prod
```

en base a los profiles que quieras.